# Indexing the body of html with Azure

Tags: azure, search, indexing

I'm trying to index a series of HTML files within an azure blob storage. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#ContentSpecificMetadata) shows that you can use the HTML file's metadeta such as keywords or title to include for indexing. Or you can index all of the text within the file, tags and all. However I specifically want to index the text within the body tag within each HTML file.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It should work using the approach described in the article.

As another option, assuming you have coding skills, you can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse the html and index just the parts you want too(e.g title, body, meta tags)

Comment: I dont want to keep the HTML tags. I want it to make the text strings from the body seachable, but not the style information. It's not clear whether

Comment: Sorry for double reply: The article says the meta data can be indexed, which are specific tagged strings, like header and description. But it doesnt really say what happens if you index the content. I dont want the tags or the style information, I just want the blocks of text within the body to be indexed. So you're saying the "content" will be stripped of that kind of stuff?

Comment: in the content type-specific metadata properties section, it says: Strip HTML markup and extract text. It you have inline css, I am not sure if it wil be ignored or not, then you'd better index it manually